# Spark filtering broadcast vars from RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning broadcast vars and trying to filter those from the RDD. This is not happening for me.

Here is my sample data

**content.txt**

```
Hello this is Rogers.com
This is Bell.com
Apache Spark Training
This is Spark Learning Session
Spark is faster than MapReduce
```

**remove.txt**

```
Hello, is, this, the
```

**script**

```
scala> val content = sc.textFile("FilterCount/Content.txt")
scala> val contentRDD = content.flatMap(x => x.split(","))

scala> val remove = sc.textFile("FilterCount/Remove.txt")
scala> val removeRDD = remove.flatMap(x => x.split(",")).map(w => w.trim)

scala> val bRemove = sc.broadcast(removeRDD.collect().toList)

scala> val filtered = contentRDD.filter{case (word) => !bRemove.value.contains(word)}

scala> filtered.foreach(print)
```

> Hello this is Rogers.com This is Bell.comApache Spark TrainingThis is
>   Spark Learning SessionSpark is faster than MapReduce

As you can see above, filtered list still contains the broadcast vars. How can i remove these?

Comment: Are you sure your check for `"Hello".contains("Hello this is Rogers.com")` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are splitting a file with `","`, But your file is delimited with space `" "`.

```
scala> val content = sc.textFile("FilterCount/Content.txt")
scala> val contentRDD = content.flatMap(x => x.split(","))
```

Replace this with

```
scala> val content = sc.textFile("FilterCount/Content.txt")
scala> val contentRDD = content.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
```

Use this to ignore case

```
val filtered = contentRDD.filter{case (word) =>
     !bRemove.value.map(_.toLowerCase).contains(word.toLowerCase()
)}
```

Hopr this should work!

Comment: Thanks! a classical mistake which i couldn't catch even after spending couple of hours since i wasn't looking in the right place. +1 for showing ignoreCase.